# Bash shell doesn't display Python output

Tags: command-line, bash, python, vim

I started using vim + tmux for my programming and suddenly after accidentally smashing couple of keys [Forgive me I am a klutz] the bash shell started acting weirdly.

When I run my unittest written in Python they don't seem to have run, since there is no output on the shell. However if I press 'ENTER' twice the output shows up just fine. Other outputs such as `ls` work just fine, so only Python seems to be affected by this.

Here is a list of commands I've run that haven't fixed the problem.

1. `reset`
2. `stty sane`

The problem also persists if I use a different terminal aside from the default one. For example I tried using xTerm and ran into the same problems. So it seems that the problem isn't at the terminal level but the shell itself.

Comment: can you run the command `history` and paste it to http://paste.ubuntu.com?

Comment: @Tim here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14570014/

Comment: It is obviously line 850 (`[[ooo`)in your history. I can't do anything with it, but may my comment help others solve your problem